# LINQ generating wrong SQL for empty string

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code:

```
var approver = _context.approver.Where(x => x.ApproverName != "").Select(x => x.ApproverUserId).Distinct();
```

And the generated SQL is

```
SELECT DISTINCT "x"."approveruserid"
FROM "approver" "x"
WHERE (("x"."approvername" <> '') OR "x"."approvername" IS NULL )
```

I'm expecting the SQL should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT "x"."approveruserid"
FROM "approver" "x"
WHERE (("x"."approvername" <> '') OR "x"."approvername" IS NOT NULL )
```

So, the generated SQL is missing the `NOT` clause and this causes to return wrong result. By the way, I'm using Oracle Database. In Oracle, `null` equals to empty string.
How to fix it?

[UPDATE]: I'm using

```
var approver = _context.approver.Where(x => x.ApproverName.Length > 0).Select(x => x.ApproverUserId).Distinct();
```

as a workaround. But I'm open to another suggestion that can generate the SQL properly for empty string checking.

Comment: The IS NOT NULL condition in your expected query makes no difference, the <> condition can only be true for non-null values.

Comment: @jarlh I'm getting wrong result if the `NOT` clause is not there.

Comment: And by the way, I'm using Oracle.

Comment: What is your expected result? I mean what should happen to rows where approvername is null?

Comment: I'm expecting it to return records that has approver name not an empty string or null.

Comment: What is `Where(x => x.ApproverName = "")` translated to?

Comment: why not add an additional condition checking != null ?

Comment: @jarlh I want to retrieve non empty approver name, so I'm using `x.ApproverName != ""`. Not `ApproverName = ""`

Comment: @Dbuggy That will give me this : `("x"."approvername" <> '') OR "x"."approvername" IS NULL)) AND "x"."approvername" IS NOT NULL`. The actual problem lies in the clause `IS NULL`. It is generated wrongly.

Comment: @rcs I wouldn't know why the provider generated the additional OR part. But you should have the right results now.

Comment: @Dbuggy That additional OR part is the one causing problem. If I use that syntax, the generated SQL will be wrong. I have to use another way already.

Answer (score 0):

The generated SQL is correct. You are asking for the string to be something other than "", and `null != ""`.

`String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is not supported by Linq to SQL but your workaround works fine.

Alternatively you can use something like this:

```
_context.approver.Where(x => (x.ApproverName ?? "" ) != "")
```

Comment: In Oracle, `null = ""`.

Comment: And for others null != "" is unknown, not true.